# How do you output a path that includes relationship types?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Matching and returning a path should return the nodes and the relationships between them in path order.

According to the Cypher documentation, this should include the relationship types. If you look at the [developer docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/), and search for any query that ends with `return p`, the returned pattern always includes the type of each relationship, such as:

```
[Node[2]\{name:"Michael Douglas"\},:ACTED_IN[5]\{role:"President Andrew Shepherd"\},Node[6]\{title:"The American President"\}]
```

However, in the Neo4j 3.0.3 browser (and assuming other versions as well, haven't seen the fix in the 3.0.4 changelog), any output of a relationship (whether as part of a path or otherwise) returns the relationship properties only, or an empty object {} if no properties exist. The type doesn't output at all:

```
[{name: Black}, {}, {name: Red}, {}, {name: Yellow}, {}, {name: Black}, {}, {name: Blue}]
```

I can output the relationships separately, in another column by adding this to the return:

```
EXTRACT(rel in RELS(path) | TYPE(rel)) as relType
```

But what I really want is the path output (lists of nodes and relationships between each node) but including the relationship type.

Is there some option I can turn on, or some other function or query workaround that outputs this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the browser, you can click on the `Code` tab (on the lefthand side of the response panel, underneath `Graph`, `Rows`, and `Text`) to see the full `Response` (in the `Commit Transaction` box on the right).

Alternatively, you can download the full response in a JSON (or CSV) file using the download icon at the top of each query panel.

The full response contains all the relationship data and metadata (including the relationship type).

[UPDATED]

The `Code` pane shows you the `POST` requests that the browser web app makes to the neo4j transactional endpoint. So, the results in that pane are actually the same results that any client would receive for the same request.

However, when you make the calls yourself, you can reduce the amount of data returned (much of which is redundant or perhaps uninteresting) by modifying the optional arguments in the payload of the "Commit Transaction". For example, you can try specifying a `resultDataContents` array with just a "graph" element, and omitting the "includeStats" argument entirely. The response will basically just contain the "graph" data elements.

Comment: It's true that the relationship data is there, and that can be helpful when processing it programmatically, but as far as an at-a-glance easily-human-readable representation, it doesn't quite fit the bill. The relationships are still separate from the nodes in the output. Also, the relationship type is in the graph section, not the meta section. Does that section return when not querying it from the browser?